# Convert Firebase Data To Formated Google Sheet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

[image]

I need to Store **ApplyForCompany** Data in Google Sheet.
Can anyone help me to solve out this problem?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question following of below link

[Data To Formated Google Sheet](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-send-app-data-to-a-web-spreadsheet-google-sheets/)